# How to set srid of a single point coordinates pair?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I think is better explain with a small example:
selected a geometry point i get it back in a coordinate pair

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON('010100002031BF0D009A999919F9BD2D41CDCCCC4C758E5241')
--result:
"{"type":"Point","coordinates":[974588.55,4864469.2]}"
```

to return back the geometry simply i make

```
SELECT ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(974588.55 4864469.2)')
```

having for example the same pair of coordinates but in a different "form" (srid?)

```
coordinates:[9.7458855,48.644692]}
```

How i can transform them into the previous pair?
I know,i'm a bit confused about all this stuff, where i can find a good reading source?

Comment: ST_Transform is the SQL function you want. There are plenty of examples in http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html

Comment: i have read documentation but i have not find the way, because i don't know in what type of srid they are, i'll try to look better, where i can find a guide to understand difference between srid systems?

Comment: Do you know anything about projections?

Comment: no, i'm noob, i think wiki can be a good starting projected point :)

Comment: There are lots of hits you can get from google searches, but because the concept is inherently about converting from 3D to 2D, I think animations help, which is why the online course I put into my answer is a good idea.

Comment: wow thanks Sir, I was looking for something like this, there is much material but it is often very abstract or very specific for people like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not familiar with projections and the like, you might want to do the NOAA course on this: http://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/training/datums (note that you do need Flash, and its narrated so you need sound; but you can skip the registration if you like, and the ArcGIS specific parts at the end are obviously not needed).

Once you have an understanding of what type of changes you are making, then you can do the change.

Note that the SRID for some data types (including WKT and WKB) is implicit (usually mapped to SRID of 0 or -1; indicating "unknown"). Therefore you have to know where the data came from, or guess the SRID based on knowing what some of the data represents. There are extensions to WKT and WKB that are used in PostGIS that make it explicit.